# Increasing nproc limit for a non-root user . Only effective by restart

Tags: linux, limit, etc, thread

I am increasing `nproc` limit for one of a development user account in my rhel6 system . After searching some rubust solution , I zerod at editing `/etc/security/limits.conf` with these two lines :

```
@dev_user        hard    nproc          4096
@dev_user        soft    nproc          4096
```

For some cases I have to deal with so much number of threads that's why I want those numbers high . Also this solution serves the pupose well . BUT my problem is if any time I edit that file with `sudo` permission then it only becomes after the system restart.

This dev_user have been provided `root` access with `sudo` permissions only. Here is my humble request to you to please suggest me some solution which should do the task without restart . Also increased limits should last long until unless no else edits it again.

Comment: Restarting the entire system for a `limits.conf` change to take effect is like burning down your whole house to get rid of a spider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The settings specified in `/etc/security/limits.conf` are applied by `pam_limits.so` (`man 8 pam_limits`).
The pam stack is only involved during the creation of a new session (login). Thus you need to log out and back in for the settings to take effect.